# My buttons won't start and stop the function that is called from an outside module

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

The function works when called inside the GUI by just placing R.loop(). However, it doesn't run with a button click. I've tried using .configure, but that doesn't work. The module works fine on its own inside the source code as well. I thought I heard somewhere that Tkinter doesn't like globals, but I'm not sure.

```
    #creating a global variable for running loop
    global Run
    Run=False
    
    #begin GUI CODE
    
    main = tk.Tk()
    main.title('REGENERATOR')
    main.geometry('800x800')    
    
    ...
    
    #THIS IS THE CALL OF FUNCTION SETUP
    
    running_setup=R.setup()
    
    #Funtion to initialize the motor
    
    def motor():    
        if Run(True):
            R.loop()
    
    #This is the start button
    
    def startmotor():   #Function to start motor
        global Run
        Run = True
        #Button_run.configure()
    
    Button_run=Button(frame5, text="run", command=lambda:startmotor, bg="white", fg="black", padx=5, pady=5, font=("Times", 16))
    Button_run.grid(row="2", column="0")        
    
    #This is the stop button
    
    def stopmotor():
        global Run
        Run = False
        #Button_stop.comfigure()
    
    Button_stop=Button(frame5, text="stop", command=lambda:stopmotor,  bg="white", fg="black", padx=5, pady=5, font=("Times", 16))
    Button_stop.grid(row="2", column="1")
```

Comment: This code does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Note that `command=lambda:startmotor` does not execute `startmotor()` when the button is clicked.  Remove `lambda:` or change it to `command=lambda:startmotor()`.